# Power BI Admin Portal - Unable to assign access to workspaces to an AAD group

Tags: powerbi

In the PBI service, if I click on Workspaces in the left-hand side menu, select a workspace and then Workspace Access, I can start entering an AAD group, to assign access, and I get a dropdown of all groups matching what I have entered so far.  However, if I access the same workspace from the Admin Portal | Workspaces page, I am not able to enter any AAD groups and I get no dropdown as I start typing the name of an AAD group. Is this working as designed? Am I doing something wrong?